# Kafka publishing in multiple threads to the same partition

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have some thousands of records to be posted to Kafka on the same partition in one transaction. I am doing this using spring KafkaTemplate. In order to improve the performance of my current logic, I am thinking of doing Kafka publishing in multiple threads. All the events to be published  have the same key and are intended to go to same partition. Will using multiple threads result in offset conflicts among multiple threads? Should I stick to one thread doing all publishing?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is bound to the thread so you'll end up with multiple transactions.

Have you tried increasing the `linger.ms` producer property?

Answer (score 0):

We are using multi-threaded approach in a spring app to publish msgs to same Kafka topic, no issue has been reported yet. Kafka is a commitlog based process and appends the new messages into the log and gives the offset out to zookeeper to manage consumers.

Your approach is same as multiple producers sending messages simultaneously to a topic, with same key. Kafka can handle this scenario since there is an elected partition leader.

Also there is a buffer time till when produced messages are backedup into the producer buffer and are flushed when the buffer space is full. So Kafka already has mechanisms to take care of bombardment of messages with same key.